# Выполнение DRY на практике

Tags: php, laravel, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования, dry

Всем привет. Пишу на laravel. Есть 2 метода в контроллере `UserController`:

```
/*
*@param EditUserRequest $request
*@return view
*Изменяет данные и роль пользователя.
*/
public function edit(EditUserRequest $request)
{
        $user = User::find($request->user_id);
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->surname = $request->surname;
        $user->phone = $request->phone;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        if($request->role_id == 3) {
            $user->manager_id = $request->manager_id;
        } else {
            $user->manager_id = null;
        }
        $user->save();

        $user->syncRoles([$request->role_id]);
        return redirect()->route('users.index')->with('success', 'Пользователь изменен.');
}
/*
*@param ConrirmUserRequest $request    
*@return view
*Подтверждает пользователя и назначает ему роль, которую отправил админ
*/
public function confirm(ConfirmUserRequest $request)
{
        $user = User::find($request->user_id);

        if (!$user->notActivated()) {
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Пользователь уже подтвержден');
        }
        $user->is_activated = 1;
        if($request->role_id == 3) {
            $user->manager_id = $request->manager_id;
        } else {
            $user->manager_id = null;
        }
        $user->save();
        $user->assignRole($request->role_id);
        return redirect()->route('users.index')->with('success', 'Пользователь подтвержден.');
 }
```

В обоих методах есть код, который повторяется. К примеру, проверка пользователя, равняется ли id его роли 3:

```
if($request->role_id == 3) {
            $user->manager_id = $request->manager_id;
        } else {
            $user->manager_id = null;
        }
```

А также место, где проверяется, подтвержден ли данный пользователь на данный момент:

```
if (!$user->notActivated()) {
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Пользователь уже подтвержден');
        }
```

Понимаю, что на этом полностью нарушаю DRY и зону ответственности контроллера. Поэтому хочу узнать у более опытных людей, куда выносить данные методы? К примеру, метод проверки `role == 3` не может быть вынесен в данном случае в модель, поскольку данные зависят от $request, а не от модели.

Comment: @entithat а причем тут middleware? Они уже настроены, мы же изменяем данные другого пользователя, а не того, который сейчас залогинен в системе. Т.е. нужно перед тем, как сохранить данные в БД, проверить роль, которую мы сохраняем пользователю. Если ID роли равен 3, то у пользователя должен быть менеджер, иначе ID менеджера `null`.

Comment: Да, действительно, не дочитал вопрос. Я думаю, что ничего страшного если такая маленькая проверка повторится два-три раза. Можете просто записать в таком виде: `$user->manager_id = ($request->role_id == 3) ? $request->manager_id : null;` чтобы не мозолила глаза. Разве что, чтобы не повторять само условие, то можете засунуть в модельку, а там в контроллере просто вызывать каждый раз её.

Comment: @Alexxosipov если код с role == 3 повторяется только в контроллере, то можно сделать protected метод userSaveManagerByRoleId($roleId) в самом контроллере, иначе такой же public метод но в модели. notActivated не вижу где повторяется.

Comment: Создайте прослойку между контроллером и моделью, что-то типа UserService. Контроллер передаст туда все данные, и ворочайте там как хотите.